# How can I understand whether an eclipse application is e4, e3 or compatibility is enabled?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

How can I understand whether the eclipse application is e3, e4 or whether compatibility is enabled between e3 and e4 ?

Where should I look at?

Comment: `org.eclipse.e4.*` plugins means e4 and `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3` plugin means compatibility layer. See https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2016/01/08/migrating-from-eclipse-3-x-to-eclipse-4-e4/

Comment: All Eclipse applications contain the e4 code because that is the core of Eclipse these days. Applications using the 3.x compatability layer have the org.eclipse.ui.* plugins as well